# Convert .NET detached signature verification to bouncycastle

Tags: c#, hash, bouncycastle

I'm trying to convert the following code (which uses .NET's built-in cryptography libraries) to BouncyCastle.  Unfortunately, between the lack of documentation, the confusion with all the Java BC questions, and the unusualness of working with detached signatures, I can't figure out how to do this.

.NET code:

1) Code I need to convert:

```
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi!");
var signature = File.ReadAllText("Signature.p7s");
byte[] hashedDocument = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA256").ComputeHash(data);
var cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(hashedDocument), true);
cms.Decode(Convert.FromBase64String(signature));
cms.CheckSignature(true);
```

2) Code to generate the p7s:

```
var data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToSign);
var hash = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(data);
ContentInfo ci = new ContentInfo(hash);
SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(ci, true);
CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(new X509Certificate2(cert, pw));
signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;
signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("sha256RSA");
signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9DocumentName(cert.SubjectName.Name));
signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime());
cms.ComputeSignature(signer);
var enc = Convert.ToBase64String(cms.Encode());
File.WriteAllText(sigFile, enc);
```

I've tried BouncyCastle's `RsaDigestSigner`, `CmsSignedData`, `CmsSignedDataParser`, and `SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withRSA")` (which  just returns the `RsaDigestSigner`), but none of them seem to have both a way to understand the p7s file and actually verify that it applies to the specified data.

Comment: I'll also accept an answer of "You're not storing it correctly, and if you change it to ..." if that's the case.

Comment: So.. do you have a sample of `NET code: signature is a detached SHA256 RSA signature stored Base64-encoded in a p7s file` or code to create one?

Comment: @zaitsman - I've added the code to generate my p7s to the question for posterity, but your answer below gave me what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So considering how you haven't provided an example on how you are generating the detached signature, I had to make some assumptions.

The code below was run in .net Core 3.0.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Whatever
{
    class Program
    {
        static string cert = "MIIJmQIBA.... // This here is base64 encoded PFX for the purposes of the demo ONLY";
        static string pwd = "password";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hi!");

            var hash = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA256").ComputeHash(data);

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(cert), pwd);

            // So since I've no idea how you got p7s, i improvised here:
            var cms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(hash), true); // true -> Detached
            var signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, certificate);
            cms.ComputeSignature(signer);
            var data2 = cms.Encode();

            // assuming this was in p7s file
            var xx = Convert.ToBase64String(data2);

            // this passes, this is the .Net validation from OP
            var cms2 = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(hash), true);
            cms2.Decode(Convert.FromBase64String(xx));
            cms2.CheckSignature(true);

            // Same in bouncy castle:
            BCUtil.Validate(certificate, hash, xx);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is our `BCUtil` class:

```
using System;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Cms;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Whatever
{
    public class BCUtil
    {
        public static void Validate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert, byte[] hash, string whatToValidate)
        {
            // My understanding is that you always need a cert to validate a signature with BC, but you only need a PUBLIC key
            var certificate = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert);

            // hash here
            var processable = new CmsProcessableByteArray(hash);
            // and signature here, for full .Net convert to old using() {} syntax
            using var str = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(whatToValidate));
            var cms = new CmsSignedData(processable, str);
            var signers = cms.GetSignerInfos();
            var signersCollection = signers.GetSigners();

            foreach(var signer in signersCollection.Cast<SignerInformation>())
            {
                if (signer.Verify(certificate.GetPublicKey()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("yes banana"); // pass
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("no banana"); // fail
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```